# Any tips when applying from Master's to PhD programs at different institutions?

Tags: phd, masters

I'm most likely going to be defending my master's thesis by December of this year, so I can graduate. Depending on the results, my work could be submitted for publication or not. My program is relatively new and small. I'm going to be applying soon to PhD programs at different schools or contacting different professors with labs before December. If I get accepted, I'll be starting in Fall 2017. My undergrad and grad GPA are good and I might need to retake the GRE in order to increase my math score. Can I get some tips or advice on how to become a better PhD applicant? Or, is there anything else I might be missing before applying? 
Thanks.